# show that:there exist $x\in A,y\in B$,such $x\equiv y\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

let $p$ be odd prime,$a,n,m$ be positive integers,such $(a,p)=1$,and $a\cdot(n+m)-a\cdot(n+1)>p,a<m$,if
$$A=\{a\cdot(n+1),a\cdot(n+2),\cdots,a\cdot(n+m)\}$$
$$B=\{n+1,n+2,\cdots,n+m\}$$
show that:there exist $x\in A,y\in B$,such
$$x\equiv y\pmod p$$

I try:

since $|A|=|B|=m$,

(1):if $m\ge p$,then it is clear,because $B$  complete residue system of modules $p$ is traversed,so prove this case

(2):if $m<p$,I can't prove it, I give some examples to understand this conclusion. It seems very obvious, but I don’t know how to prove it：such if
$$A=\{3,6,9,12,15,18,\},~~B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},~~~~p=5,7,11,13$$
$$A=\{10,15,20,25,30,35\},~~~B=\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}~~~p=3,5,7,11,13,\cdots$$
and so on

Comment: Note that changing $n \lt m$ to $a \lt m$ should make your question correct (this is because then each value increase between elements in $A$ would be less than the span of values in $B$). Please check to see if that is the case. Note I just deleted my answer with an example of $a = 7$, $p = 5$, $n = 1$ and $m = 2$ as I'm quite sure there's just a typo in your question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan,oh,it's $a<m$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan,if each value increase between elements in A would be less than the span of values in B,why there exist $x,y?$ Thanks?